# Как подключить стороннюю библиотеку после форка

Tags: android, fork

Переодично возникает проблема, когда нужно исправить тот или инной параметр сторонней, открытой библиотеки. Затянул, исправил, собрал, взял *.jar или другой файл, или подлючил целый модуль и радуешься. Но это не удобно, по нескольким  приччинам. Возникает вопрос:

Как подключить библиотеку из гита после форка, но без публикации её на Bintray, jCenter и т.п.?

Впервую очередь интересно для Андроида, но мысли и предложения из других платформ я думаю тоже будут интересны.

Comment: Наверное самый простой вариант: https://jitpack.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо woesss. Я давно пробовал этот вариант, но тогда возникли проблемы и я его просто игнорировал. В этот раз всё чётко получилось, оставлю последовательность действий, мб кто-то будет искать.

1. Сделали форк либы.
2. Стянули, сделали изменения, запушили.
3. Взяли ссылку на репозиторий.
4. Перешли по адресу: https://jitpack.io/
5. Вставили ссылку в строку поиска и нажали "Look":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

6. переходим на вкладку commits:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

7. и берём тот что подписан -SNAPSHOT (у меня другие не заработали, мб кто знает причины, напишите плз в коментарии) и нажимаем GetIt.
8. берём линку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

9. добавляем в зависимости и радуемся.